# Gmail for business - forward all emails from old domain to new domain

Tags: email, gmail

We have a domain using Gmail for business for emails, we are changing our domain , is it possible to route\forward all email to new domain (we are using same address for new emails, only the part after the @ is changed)

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you ask their customer support?

Comment: yep, I guess you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My organization recently added a second domain. This is done from your domain panel. [See help.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en) I would just recommend adding the the new domain as a alias of the old one, so that both email endings are recognized. [See google warning about changing the primary domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/54819?hl=en)

Don't forget to set up authentication on the new emails and update the authentication on your DNS providers site if you are rerouting to a new nameserver. Our emails were hitting spam filters for a week before we caught it.